# How do I obtain a valid token for updating layer definition in a feature service?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api

I'm attempting to automate data updates of an ArcGIS Online feature service using the REST API.

So far, I've been able to successfully:

1. Get a valid token from `https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/generateToken`
2. Upload a new GeoJSON file to `https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/users/{user}/items/{feature}/update`, passing in the token from step #1
3. The above does not seem to update the service, so I republish by passing my token and `{overwrite:"true"}` to `https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/users/{user}/publish`

This is great, it meets the original goal of having an updated dataset in an automated fashion. However, any default styling I configure for the layer goes *poof* when I republish it. To fix this, I'm trying to use the functionality at `https://services5.arcgis.com/{id}/ArcGIS/rest/admin/services/{service}/FeatureServer/0/updateDefinition` to pass in the renderer and label information that I'd like to use. Whenever I pass in the same token for steps 3 & 4, it replies with:

```
{"error":{"code":498,"message":"Invalid token.","details":["Invalid token."]}}
```

When I check the info from that endpoint to make sure I don't have to go someplace else for my token, I see it is nearly the same URI that I used in step 1. Changing my token URI to the new value doesn't seem to make the token any more valid.

From `http://services5.arcgis.com/{id}/ArcGIS/rest/info?f=pjson`:

```
{
    "currentVersion" : 10.41, 
    "fullVersion" : "10.4.1.210", 
    "owningSystemUrl" : "http://www.arcgis.com", 
    "owningTenant" : "{id}", 
    "authInfo" : 
    {
        "isTokenBasedSecurity" : true, 
        "tokenServicesUrl" : "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/generateToken"
    }
}
```

I can visit the endpoint above in my browser and it allows me to edit it without a problem (inspecting my browser traffic shows that it does not pass a token in the post, but instead a cookie with authentication inside)

I've tried requesting a separate token specifically for this one call, and I've tried passing in a `{ serverURL: 'http://services5.arcgis.com/{id}/arcgis/' }` parameter with that token call. Neither of those seem to work.

I feel like I'm missing something simple, but I'm running out of ideas!

Comment: What settings did you generate your token with? Try changing the referrer to a URL (assuming you're using requestIP)

Comment: I'm passing username, password, client: 'requestip', f: json, and expires 30 in the first call. The app I'm using isn't a web app, so there is no referer, just my local node.js client

Comment: Instead of requestIP, try:     'referer': "http://something.com"

Comment: That looks to have worked, thanks @KHibma ! - Can you make it into an answer so I can accept it and give you credit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found `requestip` to be somewhat unreliable. A better practice is to request a token with a `referer` instead. So, in the token request, use it with the URL of your app (or a made up, unique one):

```
'referer': "www.something.com"
```